# Why does my character not look whilst walking?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I am walking around or flying around my character cannot look, I move the touch pad but he keeps walking straight. I am on Windows 7 Home Premium. This is really annoying and it happens whilst flying as well! I tried it on my other slow PC and it doesn't happen on that, so it's this PC only but I don't know how to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: Which game is this in? Please tell exact game name.
You mention a touchpad - did you try using a USB mouse instead?

Comment: We need more details. What touch pad are you using? I sometimes that find when I play WoW, sometimes whilst using a mousepad, I can't move and turn at the same time.

Comment: The same thing happens on my laptop. I can't use the mouse to change my direction while I'm holding a movement key down. You have to either use a mouse or move, then stop and change direction, then move, etc. Poorly written drivers are probably the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I should suggest uninstalling minecraft and then re install it, if that doesn't work, then do what nakibest said and use a usb mouse instead. I would try to do both to make sure that it would work.